# Try to calculate arithmetic mean of this periodic function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-series

I'm trying to do a arithmetic mean of this periodic function:

[image: Plot]

I choose this subintervals:

$$f(t)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \frac{-2A}{t_0} t &   if  & \frac{-t_0}{2} \leq t < 0\\
             \frac{2A}{t_0}t &  if & 0 \leq t < \frac{-t_0}{2}
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

General formula

$$\overline{x}(t) = \frac{1}{T}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) dt$$

So, for this problem

$$\overline{x}(t) = \frac{1}{t_0}\left(\int_{\frac{-t_0}{2}}^0 \frac{-2A}{t_0}t dt + \int_{0}^{\frac{t_0}{2}} \frac{2A}{t_0}t dt\right)$$

I try to calculate it manually and always I get $0$, and I think thay this is imposible because is an even function, also if I put this formula in [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Ft0*%5Bintegrate%20%5B-2A%2Ft0*t,%20%7Bt,%20-t0%2F2,%200%7D%5D%20%2Bintegrate%20%5B2A%2Ft0*t,%20%7Bt,%200,%20t0%2F2%7D%5D) and get:
$$\overline{x}(t) = \frac{A}{2}$$

Thanks for your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it very carefully:

\begin{align}\overline{f}(t) &= \frac{1}{t_0}\int_{\frac{-t_0}{2}}^\frac{t_0}{2} f(t)\,dt\\
&= \frac{1}{t_0}\left(\int_{\frac{-t_0}{2}}^0 \frac{-2A}{t_0}t\,dt + \int_{0}^{\frac{t_0}{2}} \frac{2A}{t_0}t\,dt\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{t_0}\left(\left(-\frac{A}{t_0}t^2\right)\Bigg|^0_{-\frac{t_0}{2}} + \frac{A}{t_0}t^2\Bigg|^0_{-\frac{t_0}{2}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{t_0}\left(0 - \left(-\frac{At_0^2}{4t_0}\right) + \frac{At_0^2}{4t_0} - 0\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{t_0}\cdot\frac{At_0}{2t_0}\\
&= \frac{A}{2}
\end{align}

Note that the general formula is in fact

$$\overline{f}(t) = \frac{1}{T}\int_{a}^{a+T} f(t) \,dt, \text{ for some } a \in \mathbb{R}$$

so in this case you took $a = -\frac{t_0}{2}$ and correctly calculated that

$$f(t)\Big|_{\left[-\frac{t_0}{2}, \frac{t_0}{2}\right]} = \begin{cases}
-\frac{2A}{t_0}t,  & \text{if $t \in \left[-\frac{t_0}{2}, 0\right\rangle$} \\
\frac{2A}{t_0}t, & \text{if $t \in \left[0, \frac{t_0}{2}\right]$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: So much thanks for your answer and corrections :)